# Typescript assert class is inherited and not abstract

Tags: typescript

I have a list of classes which each inherit from an abstract class. I want to make to make a function which will instantiate a class from the list.

```
abstract class A {
  abstract foo(): string;
}

class B extends A {
  foo() {
    return "foo B";
  }
}

class C extends A {
  foo() {
    return "foo C";
  }
}

let classList: { id: string; class: typeof A }[] = [
  { id: "classB", class: B },
  { id: "classC", class: C },
];

function getClass(): A {
  return new classList[0].class();
}
```

Typescript complains "Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.ts(2511)"
The workaround is to to create a constructor interface:

```
interface AConstructor {
  new (): A;
}

let classList: { id: string; class: AConstructor }[] = [
  { id: "classB", class: B },
  { id: "classC", class: C },
];
```

Is there a way to tell typescript the the class from the list is not abstract so the additional interface is not required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pragmatically speaking the shortest answer here is to just use the [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) type `new()=>A` in place of `typeof A`.  You don't need a new interface, you can just use it inline.  It's even the same number of keystrokes (if you don't use spaces ):

```
let classList: { id: string; class: new()=>A }[] = [
  { id: "classB", class: B },
  { id: "classC", class: C },
];

function getClass(): A {
  return new classList[0].class();
}
```

---

If you want some programmatic way to transform an abstract constructor type into its analogous concrete constructor type, you can do that in TypeScript 4.2 and up with [`abstract` construct signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#abstract-construct-signatures) and some [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types):

```
type ConcreteConstructor<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => any> =
  (T extends abstract new (...args: infer A) => infer R ? 
    new (...args: A) => R : never) & T;
```

You can see that it works for `typeof A`:

```
type ConcreteACtor = ConcreteConstructor<typeof A>; 
// type ConcreteACtor = (new () => A) & typeof A
```

As well as other constructor types with constructor arguments or static members:

```
class D { constructor(public a: string, public b: number) { } static c = true; }
type ConcreteDCtor = ConcreteConstructor<typeof D>;
// type ConcreteDCtor  = (new (a: string, b: number) => D) & typeof D

const DC = D as ConcreteDCtor;
DC.c // boolean
console.log(new DC("a", 123).b.toFixed()); // "123"
```

Anyway, you could use that to de-abstractify `typeof A`:

```
let classList: { id: string; class: ConcreteConstructor<typeof A> }[] = [
  { id: "classB", class: B },
  { id: "classC", class: C },
];

function getClass(): A {
  return new classList[0].class();
}
```

Is it worth it compared to just writing `new()=>A`? Probably not if your constructors have no arguments, no static members you care about, and/or you're only going to refer to that type once or twice.  But there might be some use cases where having a programmatic solution would be preferable.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.2.3#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggg3gKAQVEhngQDMB7SgCgEoAuBEgSwDsBzAbjwF888KNBgBCCAKYAPCOLYATDNnyEqtOrgKEEUcRACuUNggBEqhCOM9C-foNToEAYQnTZCrBpXV6nrTv2GJmaOlpo2AmzAALbiYAAOcOIIAMoAFpRQMpAamsi6SPZgADIskEw4CCxyTKycXAXCTGziAO4IPgC8AHwevADaALoIHQh9moQVVUzGQugWADQN6ExivPPjuJXVJrNgIYu7TM5rmgM8muR6bPAslEYcuo6F9ExKG-4GRs1tuyWQfQAGAYAOl29CsCHCeEiMXiiQQAAUoJQODAolFgBAWLBfBAAJ5xJKOO6wfziYlsEh6eAZAA8ABUXDJ5BhiNA4Ihvu1gTzgFAOGAmMA2Hj1N0iCKeh0NjRGVJme42aROa1ubz+YLKmxyOIoFgxT12Dq9QAlBAAfgQXJoPOBfIFrwNCDNTXEADddeoAGQIennQj4wlOElkzCOCAZYbB65kilUmlQWmB8SUchYLr1TQAeizCGT0dJunEYYjepGNGtTsw3rzBJTacwmk0uwQABFNrA7vHSzQ4noQMhsUQatB2BxFn2B0OQE09FEQJ7NrxmBBMUOcSNoHpxPV+AG6wWya3w5GRhTCzI41uE0m66m2xns7n8+ejye9VGK6qaMAR1Ax4sM5WnOC5QE6rY1sm96ts2XaIMeUbtmgh5FsepYQseoIIDmCAgNQeTCrBlKUHkwLICiX5tMeNDGMAxiLAAjAATAAzHQwIgMCEYAGIsJI4hyPQdD1DhxjMSxxgCIQeSIL8pQQOUWx-mO9SHChl5wVA1KlrehL3pgPT9EMIxjFomxTDshQLEsmqrOsZmTNsMyFPsNlHJC9kIGcUkUFcNx3AgDwQE8wgvB4yh+LonxWqqcn-ECoLPMJYR8EAA)

Comment: Thanks for the information! I passed over "new () => A" earlier because in my situation the constructors for the inherited classes had different parameters than the base abstract class.